# How can I run maglev-irb with an alternate stone?

Tags: ruby, irb, maglev

Now that rvm seams to handle maglev with ease I wanted to start experimenting with an image different from the standard maglev image. I created a new image using

```
rake stone:create[experimental]
```

I could now run code in a VM connected to that stone using

```
maglev-ruby --stone experimental -e <code>
```

as expected and it reported the expected stone_name. However I could not get maglev-irb to run with a similar option, judging from the usage info they do not seem to be supported. Trying

```
maglev-irb --stone experimental
```

anyway results in an error like

```
ERROR 2730 , a NameError occurred (error 2730), , global $@ is a read-only variable (NameError)
```

Maybe there is a less obvious way I am missing? It would really be convenient to play around with maglev features interactively without destroying the default VM in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be an oversite on our part.  As a workaround, try:

```
export MAGLEV_OPTS="--stone experimental"
maglev-irb
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm (besides sparing me the `--stone` in the above `ruby ...` as well :-)